# image JSON parsing

Tags: android, json, eclipse

JSON : parsing image , im having though time having JSONException can somebody help me how to parse the image and the bio?

I want to fetch the image url ; 
and fetch the other data's

JSON : parsing image , im having though time having JSONException can somebody help me how to parse the image and the bio?

I want to fetch the image url ; 
and fetch the other data's

```
{
     "results":{
        "opensearch:Query":{
        "#text":"",
        "role":"request",
        "searchTerms":"brunomars",
          "startPage":"1"
        },
        "opensearch:totalResults":"8",
        "opensearch:startIndex":"0",
        "opensearch:itemsPerPage":"30",
         "artistmatches":{
            "artist":[
             {
                "name":"Bruno-Mars",
                "listeners":"22",
                "mbid":"",
                "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/+noredirect\/Bruno-Mars",
                "streamable":"0",
                "image":[
                     {
                        "#text":"",
                    "size":"small"
                    },
                   {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"medium"
                    },
                    {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"large"
                    },
                    {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"extralarge"
                    },
                    {
                         "#text":"",
                         "size":"mega"
                    }
                ]
                },
                {
                 "name":"Bruno+Mars",
                  "listeners":"19",
                "mbid":"",
                 "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Bruno%252BMars",
                 "streamable":"0",
                "image":[
                    {
                         "#text":"",
                        "size":"small"
                    },
                   {
                        "#text":"",
                       "size":"medium"
                   },
                      {
                        "#text":"",
                      "size":"large"
                   },
                      {
                       "#text":"",
                         "size":"extralarge"
                     },
                      {
                         "#text":"",
                       "size":"mega"
                     }
                  ]
             },
                {
                 "name":"Bruno__Mars",
                  "listeners":"4",
                 "mbid":"",
                "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Bruno__Mars",
                   "streamable":"0",
                 "image":[
                   {
                         "#text":"",
                         "size":"small"
                     },
                     {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"medium"
                      },
                      {
                        "#text":"",
                      "size":"large"
                   },
                      {
                         "#text":"",
                        "size":"extralarge"
                   },
                    {
                         "#text":"",
                         "size":"mega"
                   }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "name":"BOB f\/BrunoMars",
                  "listeners":"3",
                  "mbid":"",
                 "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/BOB+f%2FBrunoMars",
                 "streamable":"0",
                  "image":[
                     {
                       "#text":"",
                       "size":"small"
                     },
                     {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"medium"
                      },
                      {
                       "#text":"",
                       "size":"large"
                     },
                     {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"extralarge"
                      },
                      {
                        "#text":"",
                         "size":"mega"
                     }
                  ]
               },
             {
                  "name":"bruno-mars (best-muzon.ru)",
                  "listeners":"26",
                  "mbid":"",
                  "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/bruno-mars+(best-muzon.ru)",
                  "streamable":"0",
                 "image":[
                   {
                      "#text":"",
                         "size":"small"
                   },
                   {
                      "#text":"",
                         "size":"medium"
                      },
                      {
                      "#text":"",
                        "size":"large"
                      },
                      {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"extralarge"
                      },
                      {
                         "#text":"",
                      "size":"mega"
                     }
                   ]
              },
               {
                 "name":"Brunomars<3<3<3<3.",
                "listeners":"3",
                  "mbid":"",
                  "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Brunomars%3C3%3C3%3C3%3C3.",
                  "streamable":"0",
                   "image":[
                   {
                         "#text":"",
                      "size":"small"
                    },
                    {
                       "#text":"",
                      "size":"medium"
                      },
                   {
                      "#text":"",
                         "size":"large"
                      },
                   {
                      "#text":"",
                      "size":"extralarge"
                   },
                   {
                        "#text":"",
                      "size":"mega"
                   }
                  ]
              },
          {
                 "name":"Eminem_Royce_Da_59_Bruno_Mars",
                "listeners":"7",
                 "mbid":"",
                  "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Eminem_Royce_Da_59_Bruno_Mars",
                  "streamable":"0",
                  "image":[
                   {
                      "#text":"",
                     "size":"small"
                     },
                     {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"medium"
                      },
                      {
                         "#text":"",
                         "size":"large"
                     },
                      {
                         "#text":"",
                        "size":"extralarge"
                      },
                      {
                         "#text":"",
                         "size":"mega"
                      }
                  ]
               },
             {
                  "name":"bruno-mars (mp3-you.ru)",
                  "listeners":"4",
                  "mbid":"",
                  "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/bruno-mars+(mp3-you.ru)",
                  "streamable":"0",
                 "image":[
                     {
                        "#text":"",
                         "size":"small"
                     },
                     {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"medium"
                      },
                      {
                       "#text":"",
                       "size":"large"
                     },
                   {
                        "#text":"",
                        "size":"extralarge"
                      },
                   {
                       "#text":"",
                        "size":"mega"
                      }
                ]
                }
             ]
         },
         "@attr":{
     "for":"brunomars"
         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: From your description, it's almost impossible to help you. Please add your code and the full stacktrace of the exception to your question.

Comment: What are you using to parse the json?

Comment: @Pieces bro i was using json , the problem is i was always encounter org.json.JSONException: Value Adelle of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Comment: Aha, 'i was using json' that helps literally 0% WHAT we're you using to parse the json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code to parse your JSON String

```
    try 
    { 
      JSONObject obj    = new JSONObject(jSon); 
      JSONObject obj1   = obj.getJSONObject("results"); 
          JSONObject obj2   = obj1.getJSONObject("artistmatches");
          JSONArray m_jArry = obj2.getJSONArray("artist");


               for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++)
               {
                  JSONObject obj4 = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                  String url = obj4.getString("url");
                 Log.e("url", url);
                }
             } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This may help you..